# Remove decimals with javascript if the result contains .00

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the .00 decimals. I´m using Number(...) for for values like 100.50 it returns the incorrect decimals.

```
Number(100.00) // 100 Perfect!
Number(100.50) // Actual: 100.5 - Expected: 100.50
```

Comment: Use `toFixed` => `console.log(Number(100.50).toFixed(2))` to get the expected.

Comment: so ... remove decimal if it's .00 but 2 digit decimals otherwise?

Comment: @JaromandaX that´s exactly what I need drop decimals if is .00

Comment: `if(number % 1 === 0){ /* rounds perfect already */ number = number.toString();  }else{ number = number.toFixed(2); }` Note: `number` always ends up a String this way.

Comment: This question needed alot more clarification on what is acutally needed to what was posted initially.

Comment: looks good to me @AlwaysHelping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd *(well, I wouldn't but you might)* do like:

```js
function numberFix(number){
  return number % 1 === 0 ? number.toString() : number.toFixed(2);
}
console.log(numberFix(100.00));
console.log(numberFix(100.5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using toFixed(n)

for example

```
Number(100.00).toFixed(2) // 100.00
Number(100.00).toFixed(0) // 100
Number(100.50).toFixed(2) // 100.50
```

Comment: Looks like AlwaysHelping beat me to it

Comment: Number(100.00).toFixed(2) returns 100.00 instead of just 100 (not dropping the .00)

Comment: I know, I explicitly showed that in my example. There isn't anything that will know how many zeros you want automatically. If you want 100.50 in a case where it has a decimal of 0.5 or 100 in case the decimal is 00 you will have to do that manually

Comment: It sounds like you want it to drop the 00 in some cases and not in others. Well you have to use different method for both of those if you want different results.

Comment: I want to drop the .00 only if it is .55 leave it as it is :)

Comment: Got it. Check my new answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to check manually and then print differently based on the result.

try this

```
var num1 = 100.50;
var num2 = 100.00;

function numToString(num)
{
   if (num - Math.floor(num) > 0)
   {
      console.log(num.toFixed(2))
   } else {
      console.log(num);
   }
}

numToString(num1); // 100.50
numToString(num1); // 100
```

Comment: Is this what you want?